# VOID pointer De-referencing using ->

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, void-pointers, typecasting-operator

```
void set_ptr(void* p)
{
    stack S;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        S.push(&p);
        if (i == 1)
            p = p->lc;
        else if (i == 2)
            p = p->mc;
        else if (i == 3)
            p = p->rc;
        else {}

        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            S.push(&p);
            if (i == 1)
                p = p->t1;
            else if (i == 2)
                p = p->t2;
            else if (i == 3)
                p = p->t3;
            else if (i == 4)
                p = p->t4;
            else {
            }

            town* ptrReady = (town*)p;
            ///////do work/////////
            //your ptr is ready//
            ///////do work/////////
            p = S.pop();
        }
        p = S.pop();
    }
}
```

I am trying to go to the next link (actually* in a Tree).
Root node is of different type and Child node is of different type , but i am using same pointer to point to both nodes using a void pointer (one by one).
but when I run the above code this gives error: "[Error] 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type"

PS:Parent node and child nodes are defined else where.

Comment: I'm puzzled by what your expectation is, after all `void*` is not a pointer to object type.

Comment: BTW you don't get this error when you try to *run* the code, you get the error when you try to *compile* the code. Because of the compiler error it's not possible to run the code. Maybe that's the source of your confusion?

Comment: BTW again, if you want to store pointers to two different types in a data structure, the usual way is to relate the different types using [inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/inheritance)

Comment: When you have a pointer `p`, and an arrow operator `->lc`, the compiler needs to know where `lc` is located, right? To do that it needs to know the value of `p`, which you have, but it also needs to know what type of object `p` points to, so that it can make sense of the member variable or method you're trying to access. It needs the offset of the member. `void*` doesn't point to any type of object - so how can the compiler figure out the offset to `lc`? `void` doesn't have an `lc`. It has nothing. It is nothing.

Comment: You are allowed to cast a pointer to `void*`, but before you use it you have to cast it back to the original type.